# Delphi 6 stored procedure on windows 7

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, windows-7, delphi-6

I work with Delphi 6 and SQL Server 2008. With Windows Vista everything runs ok. But since I change my OS to Windows 7 all my projects started to show a message when I'm trying to compile them that says

> Stored procedure (SPname) not found or doesn't exist in the server.

I look my server and it has the stored procedure with the correct name. I used an ODBC connection and try the SQL Server and the SQL Native client 10.0 but the problem continues. The projects connect to the DB with no problem until I try to run a stored procedure. If I run the same projects in a vista again they work fine. If any of you can help me I really appreciate.......

Comment: What do you mean by "when i'm trying to compile them"? Are you successfully able to compile?

Answer (score 0):

D6 runs as admin or normal user? Just to take security out of the possibilities...

Answer (score 0):

This is such the things that annoys from Microsoft products..., and the solution is to avoid the use of ODBC. Can you "translate" your project to ADO or maybe ClientDataSet? That could be the answer to your ODBC headache...